# Multi screen and tags in awesome wm

Tags: linux, window-manager, awesome-wm

Is there a way to assign names to the screens or better, to use names as displayed by xrandr (LVDS1 etc). My problem is that the VGA screen sometimes gets number 1, and sometimes 2. I would like to hardcode some windows to VGA only (for presentations).

Comment: I found partial solution but it assumes you do not change number of screens while working (good for desktops I presume). Here is the link: http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/XRandR_Screen_Table